# GItLab - The build from another repository does not work

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two projects:
**devops/deploy/landing** and **frontend/landing**.

The **gitlab-ci.yml** file is stored in **devops/deploy/landing**, and everything works fine there.

But when I add this file to the CI **frontend/landing** settings the external gitlab-ci.yml: **.gitlab-ci.yml@devops/deploy/landing** build process starts, but it writes that there are no available runners, although the same runner as for **devops/deploy/landing** is added to **frontend/landing**.

GitLab version - 13.4.3

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
    
build_node:
  stage: build
  script: 
   - docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
   - git clone https://$GIT_USER:$GIT_TOKEN@gitlab.domain.dev/frontend/landing.git
   - docker build --network host -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/landing:$VERSION . -f Dockerfile
   - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/landing:$VERSION
   - docker image rm $DOCKER_REGISTRY/landing:$VERSION
   - docker logout $DOCKER_REGISTRY
  only: 
    - master

deploy_dev1:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - apt update && apt install openssh-client -y
   - eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV" | base64 --decode)
   - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP_DEV1 /home/deploy/deploy.sh
  only: 
   - master
```

[Runner Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03iYd.png)

[Added projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpS4D.png)

Comment: can you add here your .gitlab-li.yml?

Comment: @exud Yes, I added it.

Comment: where you defined with which gitlab-runner you will be run this .gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: you need add to your .gitlab-ci.yml file string and define which gitlab-runner will be process this file ```tags: - name_of_your_runner```

Comment: Which type of runner you are using ?

Comment: @SouravAtta runner executor: docker

Comment: That's a type of executor, types of runner are (specific, group or shared). Which type of runner ?

Comment: @SouravAtta I added images of runners' configuration